# Changing color of lines that begin with * in a multi-line <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a program that works as a syntax highlighter. The only problem left is that the language should specify the ***** sign as a comment, if they appear at the beginning of **each line**. However, if they appear after any other character, they are considered a multiplication operator and not a comment sign.

The code is written in a  tag. So the program has to check the content of the div and change the color of each line if it begins with *****. This has really bugged me so any help is appreciated.

For example, say I have the following code block:

```
<div>
This is some code 
* This is a comment
notComment = 10 * 10 
</div>
```

In this example, The second line should turn to a comment whereas the third line is not a comment.

If each line of code begins with a separate `<div>` tag, the solution is easy. But since each tag can include a chunk of code, it becomes troublesome.

Comment: Thanks, I added a comment

Comment: can you show us your css of the rest of your syntax highlighter?

Comment: The css is not the problem. All that has stopped me is how to evaluate every line of the tag. I just have no clue how that is done... The code is rather large, including several functions written in JavaScript and JQuery. so it's not a coherent program either...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[...elements].forEach(el => {
  if (el.textContent.startsWith('*')) {
    el.classList.add('comment');
  }
});
```

```css
.comment {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div>Line 1</div>
<div>Line 2</div>
<div>* Line 3</div>
<div>* Line 4</div>
<div>Line * 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work for `<div>` with multiple lines... If each code line was in a separate `<div>` the solution would be very simple. But my problem is that each div tag can include tens of lines of code. So the answer should be able to loop within each div tag.

Comment: @E.F.Haghish "I have written a program that works as a syntax highlighter." Doesn't your existing code already handle dividing multiline divs into separate elements?  How are you going to highlight any part of the text without first separating them?

Comment: not really. This is the only sign which can be both an operator and a comment sign. The other are simply keywords. I have a list of keywords that I loop for. The same for numbers and other operators...